# How to install ATI Radeon 6770 drivers on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, installation, drivers, video, radeon

How to install ATI Radeon 6770 drivers on 10.04? Are there drivers for this video card at all?

Comment: did it work? does 3d graphics acceleration work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check offical support for your AMD graphichs card from:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Radeon HD 6770 is supported by rescent Catalyst drivers and you can get it from here:

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Download the package an run it.