# 6770 AMD Drivers... Nothing but trouble?

Tags: 11.10, drivers

I downloaded 11.10 a couple days ago-- so far I love it, but I'm having issues with a graphics driver for the 6770 HD Radeon card.

Firstly, if I try the two drivers from the driver program, one of them installs fine and one of them doesn't (the post-release one doesn't work at all, it fails during the DL and install). The one that does work *decreases* my performance-- just moving around windows causes minor lag.

So after some searching, I discovered this thread: [How to install ATI Radeon 6770 drivers on 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49543/how-to-install-ati-radeon-6770-drivers-on-10-04) , and I followed the directions on it. Drivers install all fine and dandy (and I did de-activate the other driver before installing), but after a reboot (which the driver install requested), my desktop is all screwy. No launchpad, nothing but a desktop and a stripped-down top bar with what I think is the file/edit/view menu from Ubuntu's explorer program (don't know the name).

I'd post screenshots for you, but I could neither access a program to do so, nor open firefox to upload them when it happens.

Also, both drivers, the one straight from AMD, and the one from the driver program caused issues with my dual monitors. I had no luck using Catalyst to change any settings either.

Answer (score 1):

Your card is listed as supported here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

Remove the open source drivers and try Catalyst

See http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide